# Retrieving the commit message and hash from a set of Github commits

Tags: git, github

I have a database of the links to GitHub commits (or hashes) of some projects. I want to do a sentiment analysis of commit comments (messages). I need to print the commit message of one given commit but from a big set of the projects.

However, how can I do this without cloning all of the projects and retrieving the information from the specific commits individually?

Comment: https://pypi.org/search/?q=github+api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [official GitHub REST API v3](https://developer.github.com/v3/), specifically the [commits endpoint of the Git database API](https://developer.github.com/v3/git/commits/) and retrieve the commit as a JSON object. The syntax is the following:

```
GET /repos/:owner/:repo/git/commits/:commit_sha
```

Replace `:owner`, `:repo` and `:commit_sha` by correct values.
For example:

```
GET https://api.github.com/repos/torvalds/linux/git/commits/8dc765d438f1e42b3e8227b3b09fad7d73f4ec9a
```

is the JSON representation of this commit:
https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/8dc765d438f1e42b3e8227b3b09fad7d73f4ec9a

with a field message containing the commit message.